# Run and kill a bash program at a scheduled time

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, schedule

I need to run a bash program at scheduled times (based on local time) on my Ubuntu 16.04. For instance, this is what I need:

**Mon-Thursday, 10AM to 6PM** AND **Friday 10AM to Saturday 6PM**: `bash runme.sh`

And once the clocked reached the end, `kill -9` the program execution.

What's the best way to achieve that, maybe through a bash script?

Comment: I can write a code in Java to achieve that, but I prefer a bash code instead.

Comment: I mean it can be any language. As long as I can simply run it and change it myself, it is fine!

Comment: No! Looks like cron is the hero here.

Comment: Does the script require any special permissions? Sudo? A display? Access to another application? Will the script run as your user? Root? A different user? A system user?

Comment: Yes `cron` will definitely start your jobs at 10am M-T-W-T-F. Your script can shut itself down at 6pm M-T-W-T and Saturday.

Comment: What should happen if the machine is powered off or in standby at the designated starting time, should it just start later or not at all for that day? What if the machine is powered off or in standby at ending time?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest but, far from elegant, way to do that is writing a small process monitor.

Let's say your monitor is named `monitor.sh`, write this inside it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Runs your runme.sh in background
/location/of/your/runme.sh &

# Gets the PID of runme.sh
RUN_ME_PID=$!

# Sleeps how much time you need:
sleep 8h 

# Kills the process:
kill -9 $RUN_ME_PID
```

Since it is a scheduled job, use `cron` to start it for you:

Append this in the end of `/etc/crontab` (as `root`):

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
 00 10 *   *  1-4 tina  /location/of/your/monitor.sh > /your/output.log
```

Do the same for your friday batch, but change your `monitor.sh` for your needs.

Don't forget to mark `monitor.sh` as an executable:

`$ chmod +x monitor.sh`

For more information, check cron `man-pages` or some useful examples [here](https://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html)

Comment: If Friday you are sleeping 32 hours if I read the project scope correctly.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Another solution is using the "self shutdown approach" as you pointed in the answer above. :)

Comment: Another solution is use the command `at` at the end of the script and schedule the `kill -9` time

Comment: hi, if the runme.sh kicks off a application, will the application be killed when the process is kill -9 at the end?  The process id is for the runme.sh I guess so does that also kill spawned processes?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `timeout` function. Using
`timeout 8h runme.sh` will run your script and kill it after 8h if its still running. So this means start the cronjob at 10:00 from Monday-Saturday for 8 hours:

```
# Schedule cron for the time where it should start
# m h dom mon dow user  command
00 10 *   *  1-6 tina  /usr/bin/timeout 8h /your/scipt/runme.sh > /your/output.log
```