# bash - Kill a processes if it has been running for more than one hour

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python

I have this bash script that runs a python program in Ubuntu server every 5 minutes if not already running , I want to make it kill the program if it has been running for more than one hour and rerun it.

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep -f "/home/user/crawler/panel/crawler/scans.py"
then
    echo "script running"
    # Command when the script is runnung
else
    echo "script not running"
    /home/user/crawler/env/bin/python /home/user/crawler/panel/crawler/scans.py
fi
```

Comment: You may find the `timeout` program useful - see for example [Run and kill a bash program at a scheduled time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005636/run-and-kill-a-bash-program-at-a-scheduled-time)

Comment: that what  i ended  using  , simple  and onky need to edit one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your provided script to do what you want (*quickly cooked but should do the job*) ... I tried to comment as much as I thought needed, so please read the comments in the script below.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep -f "/home/user/crawler/panel/crawler/scans.py"
then
    echo "script running"
    process_id=$(pgrep -f "/home/user/crawler/panel/crawler/scans.py") # Get the PID
    process_time=$(ps -p "$process_id" -o etime | awk -F":" 'NR==2 && NF>2{print 1}') # Get process elapsed time and print "1" if more than an houer
    [ "$process_time" == 1 ] && kill "$process_id" && /home/user/crawler/env/bin/python /home/user/crawler/panel/crawler/scans.py # If the process has been running for more than one hour then kill it and run the script again
    # Command when the script is runnung
else
    echo "script not running"
    /home/user/crawler/env/bin/python /home/user/crawler/panel/crawler/scans.py
fi
```

Comment: i ended using  timeout   function   before running  the python  script  and seems working  so far , I'll keep your solution as secondary plan

Comment: @urekmazino I am happy to help, but there is one important thing that you should keep in mind though … While `timeout` will work to kill your python program after one hour, there will be times when it will not be running for up to five minutes until your bash script runs it again … But my solution will kill it and then run it immediately thus minimizing down time :-)